# Getting an invalid initialiser error

Tags: c

Why am I getting an "invalid initializer error" for the below code?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
    int i = 2;
    int j;
    for(j = i ; j < 20; j++){
        char *p[5] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        int len = 0;
        p[0] = 'a';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are to trying to do??

Comment: @oli charlesworth: Sorry dude. Will frame questions as you said from my next post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an Array of Pointers, and you're asigning only one Pointer to it:

```
char *p[5] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
```

Use this instead:

```
char *p = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
```

If you actually want an Array of Pointers, but only set the first of them, this should be your code:

```
char *p[5] = {malloc(20 * sizeof(char))};
```

*(Or, even better: `char *p[5] = {0}; p[0] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));`)*

If this is what you want, you have to asign the letter 'a' differently - use `*(p[0]) = 'a';` instead.

**Furthermore**: you don't free your memory anymore. You should use `free(p);` to do this, otherwise it's possible that your program consumes more and more memory.

For small programs, this is no problem, because the OS frees the memory anyways after the Program has been closed.

But it's bad practice, and the reason for lots of bad software.